# Need to delete if block in file using python

Tags: python

Need help, I have file which contains text with few if conditions, I need to remove particular if condition using python code
file1.js

```
if (aaaaa == b) {
qqqq
cccc
vvv
}
```

Issue is I cant read line by line, because "}" will be left and it will be hard to remove as there will be "}" in file.
can anyone please guide
My piece of code

```
import re
file_path = "C:/Users/abcd.js" 
with open(file_path, "r") as f: 
        
    data = f.readlines() 
      
 
with open(file_path, "w") as f:   
    for line in data :  
        if line == "{if (aaaaa == b) {" :
            data = re.sub(r'if (aaaaa == b) {.*?}', '', data,flags=re.DOTALL)
            print(data)

            f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are hitting here is that `.readlines()` reads line separated by a newline escape character (`\n`) and treats them as separate entries in an array - so your `data` contains:

```py
data == ['if (aaaaa == b) {\n', 'qqqq\n', 'cccc\n', 'vvv\n', '}']
```

If something isn't working, run it through a debugger or print it to console to what the variable actually contains.

Try converting that array to a single string, then replacing the newline characters and feeding that your regex expression.

```py
with open(file_path) as f:       
    data = f.readlines() 
      
print(data)
mod_data = "".join(data).replace("\n", "")
print(mod_data)
```

Alternatively, use `f.read()` to just read a file in as a single string.

Edited:

You can try it this way and rework your regex expression.

```py
import re

file_path = "test2.py" 

with open(file_path, "r") as f: 
    data = f.readlines() 

data = "".join(data).replace("\n", "")
data = re.sub(r'if\s\(aaaaa == b\)\s\{.*?\}', 'this is a replacement', data, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(data)

with open(file_path, 'w') as f:   
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: @ZAriel - It does work - the issue is your regex pattern is wrong.  `(`, `)`, `{`, `}` and whitespace are special characters and must be escaped.  You only asked how to handle dealing with the last `}` so I suggested turning it into a string and passing it to the regex that way. See my edited answer.

Comment: @ZAriel this solution should cover your test case, hopefully you can apply it to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This example removes unneeded condition with trailing `}`

```
file_path = "a.js" 
with open(file_path, "r") as f: 
    data = f.readlines() 

with open(file_path, "w") as f:   
    removing = False
    for line in data :  
    
    if '}' in line and removing:
        removing = False
        continue
    
    if 'if (aaaaa == b) {' in line:
        removing = True
                
    if not removing: f.write(line)
```

Comment: this is removing only if condition and first line, still few lines and } are not removing